# How to grey out unchecked checkbox labels when checkbox is clicked?

Tags: javascript

I am looping through a structure outputting an undefined number of checkboxes - I am looking for a way to grey out the labels of unchecked checkboxes once 1 has been checked

I have seen a number of examples of disabling the checkboxes but that's not what I need as I want the option for multiple checkboxes to be checked for a tag filtering system

being quite new to JS I don't really know where to begin with this

Does anyone have any suggestions or can recommend any resources/ documentation?

```js
var label = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
var checkbox = document.getElementsByTagName('input[type=ckeckbox]');
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" id=""/>Label Here</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" id=""/>Label Here</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" id=""/>Label Here</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" id=""/>Label Here</label>
```

Comment: Please post your work till now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution for your problem

```js
var label = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input");
checkboxes.forEach(check => check.addEventListener("change", grayout.bind(null,check)))


function grayout(box) {

   if(!Array.from(checkboxes).some(checkbox => checkbox.checked)) return checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.parentElement.style.color = "black");
   checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
      if(checkbox.checked) return checkbox.parentElement.style.color = "black";
      checkbox.parentElement.style.color = "grey";
   })
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" id=""/>Label Here</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" id=""/>Label Here</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" id=""/>Label Here</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" id=""/>Label Here</label>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! - I'm using this in my site and logging this error: Uncaught TypeError: checkboxes.forEach is not a function at grayout - any thoughts on why?

Comment: are you using `document.querySelectorAll(...);` like me?

Comment: I am yes, exactly the same as yours

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind having the checkboxes greyed out when no one is checked, you can easily do it with the `:checked` CSS pseudo-class

```
<style>
    .greyCheckbox+label {
        color: grey;
    }

    .greyCheckbox:checked+label {
        color: black;
    }
</style>

<input class="greyCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="" id="chk1" />
<label for="chk1">
    Label Here
</label>
<input class="greyCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="" id="chk2" />
<label for="chk2">
    Label Here
</label>
<input class="greyCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="" id="chk3" />
<label for="chk3">
    Label Here
</label>
<input class="greyCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="" id="chk4" />
<label for="chk4">
    Label Here
</label>
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/4hc5dyvk/

Otherwise you can bind the changed event and apply a new class once the first checkbox has been applied.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this:

```js
// select all labels and checkboxes
var label = document.querySelectorAll('label');
var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

// iterate to each checkbox
checkbox.forEach((cb, i)=>{
    // bind clicking event
    cb.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      if(cb.checked){
        // click
        checkbox.forEach(cbb=>{
          if(cbb !== cb){
            // uncheck all others
            cbb.checked = false;
          }
        });
        // set the checked to black
        label[i].style.color = 'black';
        // iterate the labels
        label.forEach((lb, k)=>{
          if(k !== i){
            // set labels other than current one to grey
            lb.style.color = 'grey';
          }
        })
      }else{
        // unclick
        // set the unchecked label to grey
        label[i].style.color = 'grey';
      }
    });
})
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" id=""/>Label Here</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" id=""/>Label Here</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" id=""/>Label Here</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" id=""/>Label Here</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simplest solution from your perspective:

```js
// select all labels and checkboxes
var label = document.querySelectorAll('label');
var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

checkbox.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if(item.checked){
      item.parentElement.style.color='grey';
    }
    else{
      item.parentElement.style.color='black';
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" id=""/>Label Here</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" id=""/>Label Here</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" id=""/>Label Here</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" id=""/>Label Here</label>
```